# Loops through the rows of a single column in Set Range

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to iterate through the rows of a single column in the set range. I set the range as WorkingRange and then set the column I want as SystemCol. how do I loop the each in the set column? I would like to display a message box for each of the rows in the selected column that has a value. The area in the code with the ** is where I am trying to insert the code but what I get is the full column address not a single cell address.

```
'===============================================================================================
'Description: Loops through the selected site and adds in the vulnerability totals for each _
    systems
'Originally written by: Troy Pilewski
'Date: 2016-06-30
'===============================================================================================

'Declares variables
Dim ToWorkbook As Workbook, FromWorkbook As Workbook
Dim ToWorksheet As Worksheet, FromWorkSheet As Worksheet
Dim WorkingRange As Range, WholeRange As Range
Dim FromWorkbookVarient As Variant, ShipNameList() As Variant
Dim TitleString As String, FilterName As String, CurrentSystemName As String, _
    ShipNames() As String, SelectedShipName As String
Dim LastRow As Long, ShipRow As Long
Dim StartRow As Integer
Const RowMultiplyer As Integer = 47

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set ToWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set ToWorksheet = ToWorkbook.ActiveSheet

LastRow = ToWorksheet.Range("Y:Y").Find( _
    What:="*", _
    After:=ToWorksheet.Range("Y1"), _
    LookAt:=xlByRows, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious _
).Row

'MsgBox _
'    Prompt:="Y1:Y" & LastRow, _
'    Title:="Ship Range"

ShipNameList = ToWorksheet.Range("Y1:Y" & LastRow).Value

For Each Item In ShipNameList
    Dim BoundCounter As Integer
    If Left(Item, 3) = "USS" Then
        BoundCounter = BoundCounter + 1
    End If
Next Item

ReDim ShipNames(BoundCounter - 1)
BoundCounter = 0

For Each Item In ShipNameList
    If Left(Item, 3) = "USS" Then
        ShipNames(BoundCounter) = Item
'        Debug.Print ShipNames(BoundCounter)
        BoundCounter = BoundCoutner + 1
    Else
'        Debug.Print UBound(ShipNames())
        Exit For
    End If
Next Item

TitleString = "Select a ship..."

SelectedShipName = GetChoiceFromChooserForm(ShipNames, TitleString)

If SelectedShipName = "" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

ShipRow = ToWorksheet.Range("Y:Y").Find( _
    What:=SelectedShipName, _
    After:=ToWorksheet.Range("Y1"), _
    LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=True _
).Row

'Debug.Print ShipRow

StartRow = 14

If ShipRow > 1 Then
    StartRow = (RowMultiplyer * (ShipRow - 1)) + StartRow
Else
    StartRow = 14
End If

Set WorkingRange = ToWorksheet.Range("B" & StartRow & ":G" & StartRow + 38)
Set SystemCol = WorkingRange.Columns(2)

'Debug.Print WorkingRange.Address

FilterName = "Excel Files (*.xls), *.xls,Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx,All Files (*.*), *.*"
TitleString = "Scan File Selection"

**For Each rw In SystemCol
    Debug.Print rw.Address
Next rw**
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd be very well served to add `Option Explicit` to the top of your code modules to always ensure all variables must be declared.

You never declared `SystemCol` as a Range, nor `rw` as Range.

Following that adding `.Cells` to `SystemCol` in the loop ensures that you will loop through each individual cell in SystemCol. See below.

```
For Each rw In SystemCol.Cells
    Debug.Print rw.Address
Next rw
```

Comment: I will when time limit has been reached